# I need help in seeking forgiveness from Allah

Tags: allah, forgiveness, oaths

I had made an oath to Allah that I will not do a specific deed for the rest of my life.I tried my best to fulfill this oath but one day I ended up breaking the oath.I am very scared now that Allah might not forgive me cause I can't do kaffara because I'm not in a position to feed some poor people or fast cause I'm a kid and if I fast my family will want to know about my problem which I'm embarrassed to share .so is there any other way to seek forgiveness? Will Allah forgive me?

Comment: Did you reach puberty?

Answer (score 1):

Allah is the Most Merciful, Most Compassionate.

Inshallah, you can always seek forgiveness from Allah (swt) by asking him from the bottom of your heart to forgive you and He will forgive you.

Your concerns expressed in your question show that you are worried about your action and Allah's (swt) punishment. This is very good as we should always fear Allah's punishment but at the same time never lose hope in His mercy on us.

Allah (SWT) Most High says in Noble Qur'an,

> "Ask your Lord for forgiveness and then turn in repentance to Him..."
>   (11:3)

Also Allah (SWT) Most High says in Noble Qur'an,

> "O you who believe! Turn (in repentance) to Allah with sincere
>   repentance; Perhaps your Lord will remove your evil from you... "
>   (66:8)

Comment: I edited your nice helpful answer (by blockquote...) which can make a nicer formatting for the answers. God bless you for the constructive answer. ________ Since having nice formatting can make your good answers more attractive ...

Comment: Your welcome. Since having nicer formatting will make your appropriate answers more useful. God bless you/